# Declaring and initializing a global 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
//gives the error expecting a declaration

 int** my_array; 
 for (int i=0; i<200; i++)
 {
     my_array[i]= new int [200];
 }

//initialize array with zeroes
 for (int i = 0; i<200; i++)
 {
     for (int j = 0; j<200; j++)
     {
        my_array[i][j] =0;
     }
 }
```

In brief:

The 2D array is declared globally

It is initialized in the main. The main calls a function that saves `0's` or `1's` in specific cells of the array

The array is then printed by the main

Also advice whether the flow is correct?

Comment: Just for clarification, an `int**` is *not* a 2-d array.

Comment: can you please post the modified code?

Comment: `intmy_array[200][200] = {0}` but if you-re using c++ USE STL, prefer `std::vector` nobodoy like to use raw pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array of an array of 200 bools, you could use std::array and std::bitset.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <array>
//...
std::array<200, std::bitset<200>> my_array;
```

Second, your code, even if you fix the syntax error is wrong.  You would need to create my_array this way:

```
int** my_array;
//...
my_array = new int * [200];
for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i )
   my_array[i] = new int [200];
```

Then somewhere you have to delete this memory:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i )
   delete [] my_array[i];
delete [] my_array;
```

---

An alternate that creates a contiguous block and uses only two calls to `new[]`:

```
my_array = new int * [200];
int *pool = new int [200*200];
for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i, pool += 200 )
   my_array[i] = pool;
```

Then somewhere you have to delete this memory:

```
delete [] my_array[0];
delete [] my_array;
```

However I advise you use a container such as the std::array, std::bitset, std::vector, etc. instead of the `int**` approach.

Comment: what happens if you do not delete this memory? When program terminates, does this memory automatically deleted?

Comment: For almost all modern operating systems, when the process terminates, the memory is deallocated.  However it is not a habit you should get into (relying on the OS to release the memory).  What if you're writing an app where the process doesn't terminate (a critical app that must run 24 hours a day), or if you move the function to somewhere where it does matter, and the memory never gets released?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your syntax error, it's probably due to something *before* the code you have shown.

The shown code,

```
 int** my_array; 
 for (int i=0; i<200; i++)
 {
     my_array[i]= new int [200];
 }

//initialize array with zeroes
 for (int i = 0; i<200; i++)
 {
     for (int j = 0; j<200; j++)
     {
        my_array[i][j] =0;
     }
 }
```

compiles fine as the body of a function.

---

Regarding the logic, which is incorrect and which uses troublesome constructs, 
do this:

```
 auto my_array = vector<vector<bool>>( 200, vector<bool>( 200 ) );
```

where `vector` is `std::vector` from the `<vector>` header.

This avoids the raw pointers, the `new`-ing`, the loops, etc., all that you find problematic.

---

Alternatively you can declare it like this:

```
 vector<vector<bool>> my_array( 200, vector<bool>( 200 ) );
```

---

Note that a **global variable** is usually troublesome, best avoided.